# Why does UIViewController almost always require layoutSubViews?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, layoutsubviews

Before iOS7, I whatever CGRect I define to a UIView's frame, it was working.

For example:

```
imageView.frame=CGRectMake(20,20,80,80);
```

was perfectly leaving 20 x 20 margin at the top left of the screen.

Interestingly if I add another UIView with:

```
nextView.frame=CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x+imageView.frame.size.width+10,20,100,100);
```

nextView appears near imageView, so It somehow accepts X parameter for the second view but it does not accept the Y coordinate for that view too.

Now, I have to use `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to arrange all of those coordinates. Otherwise, for example, frame for `imageView` becomes `0,0,80,80` automatically. (it snaps to top-left)

I am not using any nibs and I also even tried creating `UIViewController` with custom `initWithFrame` method to set the `CGRect` before `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` but it doesn't matter.

Is there something that automatically overrides x,y of Views? Like an auto-layout system etc? I don't want to use `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method to rearrange all of those coordinates.

What is happening here?

**Update 1**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        self.frame=frame; //frame is custom variable to hold it until loadViews method

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(void)loadView{
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:_frame];

    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 80,80)];
    self.imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    [view addSubview:_imageView];

    self.textView=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x+self.imageView.frame.size.width+10, self.imageView.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width-20-(self.imageView.frame.origin.x+self.imageView.frame.size.width+10), view.frame.size.height-self.imageView.frame.origin.y-20)];
    [view addSubview:_textView];

    self.view=view;
}
```

I tried similar code in initWithFrame and also in viewDidLoad. Result was the same.

**Update 2**

I have mistakenly written "layoutSubviews" instead of "viewWillLayoutSubviews" in the question, so I fixed it: I am not creating a custom UIView but UIViewController, so it had to be "viewWillLayoutSubviews" in the question.

Comment: How are you defining your view, is it on storyboards?

Comment: set imageView.bound instead of imageView.frame

Comment: @ldindu I am not using any storyboards, it is a custom UIViewController where I create all of the views manually in code.

Comment: @CoolMonster I tried it now but it didn't work too.

Comment: where did you define those image and next views?

Comment: @ldindu I updated the question with the code.

Comment: can you call [super loadView]  on your loadView?

Comment: @ldindu I tried it now and nothing is changed :|

Comment: are you implementing viewWillLayoutSubviews?

Comment: @ldindu If I implement viewWillLayoutSubviews it works, but I am trying to stay away from it and find out the reason it resets x,y coordinates of my added views.

Comment: UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:_frame] , what value does _frame contain here?

Comment: _frame is equal to self.frame, where I set it in my custom initWithFrame method: `[[MyViewController alloc]initWithFrame:...]`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are reversing the status bar as the top left point, but in iOS7 the status is transparent is the top point is the actual top left of the screen.

You can change your coordinates or add this to you view controller :

```
 if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)])
    {
        [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
    }
```

This will reset your top left point to the bottom of the status bar.

Any way, I believe putting your layout code in those methods:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews 
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

Comment: I tried setEdgesForExtendedLayout but it didn't work. Also, entering even 200px for origin.y does not work. So subtracting statusbar's height etc from 200px, it still should not snap to the top. I am trying to stay away from viewWillLayoutSubviews. That is why I am trying to find the thing that resets my x,y values to zero :-/

Comment: What is the frame of your view, in the load view, and what happens if you move this code to viewDidLoad ?

Comment: I set view's frame to CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200). Moving this code into viewDidLoad does not change anything but If I copy the lines that I set frames for the views into viewWillLayoutSubviews, it works (as expected).

Answer (score 0):

whenever a subview is added,a UIScrollView is scrolled,Frame is set for View, layoutSubViews? is called,

Comment: I checked and really wished that I had used a UIScrollView but I had't.